# How to change Z39.50 port in Geonetwork fixing the error "Address already in use"?

Tags: java, jdom, geonetwork, z39.50

I have deployed two portals (on two tomcat instances) each of which are based on Geonetwork 2.6.0.0 which use Z39.50 protocol. By default the port for both of them is 2100 which causes the second portal to give the following error:

```
ERROR [org.jzkit.z3950.server.Z3950Listener] - Problem
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:128)
    at org.jzkit.z3950.server.Z3950Listener.run(Z3950Listener.java:69)
```

I tried to change the port according the instructions given in the following URL:
https://geonetwork-opensource.org/manuals/2.10.4/eng/developer/xml_services/system_configuration.html
To change the port, in the portal, I used xml.config.set service which refers to the Java class: org.fao.geonet.services.config.set 
But when I sent the information containing the new port using http POST to the xml.config.set, the response was not a success:

```
Error   org.jdom.text cannot be cast to org.jdom.element
```

Both portals are using jdom-1.0.jar. I tried newer versions of jdom. But I didn't succeed to give two different Z39.50 ports to the portals.

Comment: I haven't tested it but I guess the request to send should look similar to 

`<request>
  <config>
     <z3950>
        <port>10000</port>
     </z3950>
  </config>
</request>`

Comment: Anyway you should be able to change the Z39.50 port using the UI too. Check https://geonetwork-opensource.org/manuals/2.10.4/eng/users/admin/configuration/index.html

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to the UI.

Comment: @juanluisrp I tried that. It gives the error mentioned in my post above.